# Limit concurrent tasks running

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

I am trying to limit the number of concurrent tasks that can run in parallel for each call of `Create` to 5 tasks.
In my code Parallel.ForEach does not seem to do any throttling at all.
How do I limit the number of concurrent tasks `Create` creates?

```
public async Task Create(List<FormModel> forms)
 {
     var tasks = new List<Task>();

     Parallel.ForEach(forms, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, form =>
     {
         tasks.Add(makePdfAsync(form));
     });
     await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));
 }

 public async Task makePdfAsync()
 {
     var message = new PdfMessageModel();
     message.forms = new List<FormModel>() { form };

     var retry = 10;
     var uri = new Uri("http://localhost.:8007");
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

     using (var wc = new WebClient())
     {
         wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

         // reconnect with delay in case process is not ready
         while (true)
         {
             try
             {
                 await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, json);
                 break;
             }
             catch
             {
                 if (retry-- == 0) throw;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

**EDIT:** The suggestion of semaphoreSlim did not work any better. 
The solution was to move the code that limit the concurrent tasks into the try clause of `makePdfAsync()` as `tasks.Add(makePdfAsync(form))` will never be limited regardless of what thread limiting construct you use.

I had foolishly assumed the `await` from `makePdfAsync()` would make all of `makePdfAsync()` awaited higher up too..

Comment: You might try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations to see of that answers your question.

Comment: `Parallel` is for synchronous code only. The correct tool to limit asynchronous concurrency is `SemaphoreSlim`. See recipe 11.5 in my book.